# scroll-snap-type doesn't work, How can I fix it?

Tags: html, css, scroll-snap-type

It is scrolled down as it originally works, I mean, like there's no scroll-snap option. why?

html code below:

```
<body>
    <noscript>~~</noscript>
    <div id="background"></div>
    <header>
        <nav><a href="/"><img src="~~" alt="To Mainpage"></a></nav>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/">~~</a></li>
                <li><a href="/">~~</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <main>
        <div id="container">
            <section id="first">
                <h1>~~</h1>
                <article>~~</article>
            </section>
            <section id="second"></section>
        </div>
    </main>
</body>
```

and CSS code below:

```
#container {
    scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

#container > section {
    height: 100vh;
    scroll-snap-align: start;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to give your parent container a height value,
as shown in the example below.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#container {
    display: flex;
    overflow: auto;
    outline: 1px dashed lightgray;
    flex: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}

#container > section {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    scroll-snap-align: start;
    flex: none;
}

#first, #third {
  background: #ccc;
}

#second, #fourth {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <section id="first"></section>
  <section id="second"></section>
  <section id="third"></section>
  <section id="fourth"></section>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Finally it works. Anyway, Is "position: relative" option relevant with this theory?